# Including a static library in a Xcode project

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have developed a static library using the "iPhone OS->Library->Cocoa Touch Static Library" of Xcode. I compiled it and it works fine. Then I wanted to include this library in a new project. Here is what I've done :

- Create a new Xcode project "View-based application"
- Project->Add To Project : I added my static library .xcodeproj file
- Project->Edit Active Target

  - In General tab : I've added the static library in the "Direct Dependencies"
  - In Build tab   : I've added the path of the headers in the "Header Search Paths" In "Search Paths" section

Then I tried to use one of the classes I've put in my static library, but I get a linking error :

"_OBJC_CLASS_$_GenUIImage", referenced from:

Objc-class-ref-to-GenUIImage in TestViewController.o

Symbol(s) not found

Collect2: Id returned 1 exit status

I do not get what I did wrong. Please help.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. I dragged & dropped the .a (library file) into the "Link Binary With Libraries" of the main project target.

However I have an other problem.

My static library contains a class that needs the AudioToolbox framework. I added it in my static library. However I need to add the framework also inside the project. Is there a way to avoid duplicating the framework in the main project?