# Including one Xcode static Library in a project

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to do this, and get several linker error. The parent project needs to access the class XHMessage from the child project(the static library ).This is just a example , infact I need to access many classes from the child project .

Before running it , I have finished 5 steps for solving it .

Step1 :

```
Click on parent project -> build phases -> Link Binary With Libraries and add childProject.framework.
```

Step2 :

```
Click on parent project -> build phases -> Target Dependencies and add childProject.framework again .
```

Step3 :

```
Click on parent project -> build setting -> Header Search Path and add child project's path so that parent project can find those classes in child project .
I also did this for build setting -> Framework Search Path .
```

Step4 :

```
Click on child project -> build setting -> Allow Non-modular Includes in Framework Modules and set Yes .
```

Last Step :

```
add -ObjC flag at the parent project's Other Linker Flags .
```

Following Link has the same problem , but those answers do not work for me .
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4529133/including-one-xcode-project-in-another-linker-errors)

I think I've done all the things but still can't solve this problem . How can I fixed it ? orz

IDE Version :

```
Xcode 6.1
```

Comment: which is the error message?

Comment: @tkanzakic if I did't do step1 & step2  ,the error message is Linker error , but if I do it , I get build failed without any error message .

Comment: @tkanzakic I try to post some screen cut for error message but faild , because I'm new here , post image needs 10 reputation ..

Comment: Could you copy&paste error here? Does your library has all necessary slices?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Including a static library in a Xcode project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344120/including-a-static-library-in-a-xcode-project)

Comment: @Azat if I did't do step1 & step2 ,the error message is Linker error , but if I do it , I get build failed without any error message . And I try to post some screen cut for error message but faild , because I'm new here , post image needs 10 reputation ..

Comment: Which linker error exactly? Undefined symbols? Copy it as text here

Comment: @Tanuj sad , he also can't solve this problem .

Comment: @Azat Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_LKBadgeView", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in systemInfoTableViewCell.o

Comment: @Azat Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_XHMessageTableViewController", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_spMessageTableViewController in spMessageTableViewController.o

Comment: @Azat 9 Linker error，build for iphone6 and simulator iphone5s

Comment: Your library simple doesn't have 64 bit slice

Comment: @Azat this library has a demo on Github , it's ok running on iphone6 .  So I think it's not architecture support problem 0.0 .   Here is the link https://github.com/leancloud/leanchat-ios , but the ReadMe file's language is Chinese . I've asked the author how to use the library , but it doesn't work .